# Element ref was specified as a string. Backward compatibility with react-dom as external library,

Tags: reactjs, webpack, external, react-dom

I have defined externals inside of my webpack configuration like:

```
externals: [
    'react-dom-16',
    { 'react-dom': 'react-dom-16' }
],
```

react-dom-16 is a bundled react-dom with its own name.

And when I run application I got error and nothing is shown:

> Element ref was specified as a string (value0) but no owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded.

But the funniest thing is when I remove externals from webpack and put react-dom from dev-dependencies to dependencies and build everything on it. Then magicali everything works.

Probably I'm using ref as a string. But there are too many cases where should I change it, also there are old libraries I'm using and I can't access their code.
So I would like to use react 16.4.1 with backward compatibility but I got that kind of error and have no idea where to go next.

Comment: What's avid-react-dom-16 ? How is it used? Why was it specified twice in `externals`? The error means what it says, there are multiple React copies somehow. The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Changed name from avid-react-dom-16 to react-dom-16.
react-dom-16 is a bundled react-dom with its own name. To use one react-dom dependencies for few applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with circular dependencies of our externals.
It is react-dom was using react inside of it. 
So we had duplication of react.
Solution was exposing react-dom without react.